# CSS sprites background and selectors

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-sprites

Thank you in advance for any help you can give.  I am implementing sprites for the first time and am looking to streamline my code.  Below is my css and html.

CSS

```
div[class^='Rating']
{ 
    background:url('http://10.0.50.19/images/Ratings.png') no-repeat;
    width:68px; 
    height:13px; 
    display:block;
}
.Rating0_5 { background-position: 0px 0px; }
.Rating1_0 { background-position: 0px -13px; }
.Rating1_5 { background-position: 0px -27px; }
.Rating2_0 { background-position: 0px -41px; }
.Rating2_5 { background-position: 0px -55px; }
.Rating3_0 { background-position: 0px -69px; }
.Rating3_5 { background-position: 0px -83px; }
.Rating4_0 { background-position: 0px -98px; }
.Rating4_5 { background-position: 0px -112px; }
.Rating5_0 { background-position: 0px -125px; }
```

HTML

```
<div class="Rating0_5"></div>
<div class="Rating1_0"></div>
....
```

The issue I am having is the background-position is always being set to `0px 0px` as I believe the first style is overriding the background-position elements (according to Firebug).  If I copy copy the `background:url('http://10.0.50.19/images/Ratings.png') no-repeat;` to each of the `.RatingX_X` styles it works fine but I don't want to repeat the `background-image` and repeat text if I don't have to.  Hopefully this makes sense. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The easiest and most cross-browser way would be to add a common class on your elements (`<div class="Rating Rating0_5"></div>`) and then simply change `div[class^='Rating']` to `.Rating`.
- Your other possible solution is to fix the [**selector specificity**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity) in your code.
  Either use simply `[class^='Rating']` or write your class selectors as `div.Rating0_5`.

Comment: Interesting.  Thanks for the input. I will look into this as well.

Comment: @user752459 Please check my update, the second one seems to be the easiest fix.

Answer (score 4):

Define your first rule as:

```
div[class^='Rating']
{ 
    background-image:url('http://10.0.50.19/images/Ratings.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width:68px; 
    height:13px; 
    display:block;
}
```

and it should work.

On your `background:` you are not definin the position so it assumes it is on the default 0 0, and since your first selector is more specified as your background-position selectors it overrides.

Comment: Worked like a charm and makes perfect sense.  I appreciate the help.  I will mark this is the answer once the site lets me.  Thanks easwee.

Comment: @user752459 Np - was a pleasure.