# css selector specificity conflicts due to multiple stylesheets

Tags: css, css-selectors, conflict, css-specificity

Ok, I've  been reading through stackoverflow css selectors.  on the thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5992670/css-sprites-background-and-selectors) what is the differences in this syntax?  What does the ^= mean? What is it selecting? all?

```
[class^='Rating']
```

and

```
div.Rating0_5
```

Also, there's a statement [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity) that reads:
***Note: Repeated occurrances of the same simple selector are allowed and do increase specificity.***

What does that mean?

I'm asking because I'm having to clean up alot of CSS code on a website.  There are over a dozen stylesheets each containing 200+ lines of code, and there are styles that are overriding each other among the stylesheets, maybe even within them if repeated occurences increase specificity.  It's painstaking to go line by line through the stylesheets to find out what particular class, div, etc is over-riding another and some of the specificity is seven selectors deep! It's almost impossible for me and very stressful.

Is there a tool to use that will target styles overwriting other styles?  Is it easy to use and what does it do exactly?  If not, how can I write my CSS with enough specificity without having extremely long selectors to hopefully ensure uniqueness so that they will not be overwritten by another stylesheet of rules?

Thanks, I hope this makes some sense and someone has had this experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

^= is "starts with" for CSS selector. In your case it will apply to classes with names starting with "rating".

With traditional CSS you do have to make really long selectors to be specific and I think the statement meant you can have duplicate selector and the styling will be combined.

In terms of cleaning up the CSS I don't have a good suggestion for an automated tool but you can take a look at http://sass-lang.com/ (SCSS) for a better syntax layer on top of CSS that does variable and inheritance of selectors. Does clean up CSS a lot.

Comment: --thanks.  I'll check out the SCSS I was also reading the w3.org docs too.  Now what is the diff between these two and which has more specificity or are the duplicate and if they are duplicate, which would override the other?  `div[class^='Rating']` and  `div.Rating0_5`

Comment: then it comes down to what rule gets specified later. For example:
    `div[class^='Rating'] {
      color: blue;
    }`

    `div.Rating0_5 {
      color:black;
    }`

then test will be black.